# CommitPooler and Pooler threads in tomcat

Tags: tomcat

Recently, when we are tracking our product problems, this two thread have become appear too much.
My question is any one have an idea what are this two threads do?

Answer (score 1):

They aren't Apache Tomcat threads - they mut be created by your application or a library it is using. Take a thread dump and the stack traces for those threads should give you a pretty good idea what code they are associated with.